# Regexp JS from referrer

Tags: javascript

I need to check if a referrer has word "profile" i need to put profile/(.*?) in a var. How can I do it in js?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ref = document.referrer;
if( ~ref.indexOf("profile") ) {
  alert('coincidence found!');
}

 </script>
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: var ref = '';
    if(document.referrer.indexOf('profile') >= 0) {
     ref = String(document.referrer).substr(document.referrer.indexOf('profile'));
    }
    alert(ref);

Comment: Vismari thanks, but i don't need word "profile/" in out(only all chars after slash)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var str="Is this all there is?";
var patt1=/[^a-h]/g;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
</script>
```

Result :I,s, ,t,i,s, ,l,l, ,t,r, ,i,s,?

check [link The [^abc] expression is used to find any character not between the brackets.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_charset_not.asp)

and this tooo [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
var ref = document.referrer;
ref.match(/(?:profile).+/,(match)=> {
    console.log(match)
})
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: Do you read the question?The code only capture the Referer url has the start with (profile) to then end. For example ref = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287277/regexp-js-from-referrer/56375373#56375373?profile=12313',and the Regexp only get match the string 'profile=12313'